# Why does the following piece of code delivers different results?

Tags: c#, .net

these are the functions for 128 bit `XorShift` PRNG, and by just looking at code I could never thought that a difference in types (Int32 / UInt32) might yield to different results. In both cases we operate the same sets of bits that are shifted the same amount bytes left or right, why do we get different results then?

```
Int32 XorShift128(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 z, Int32 w)
{
    var t = x ^ (x << 11);

    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = w;

    return w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8);
}

UInt32 XorShift128(UInt32 x, UInt32 y, UInt32 z, UInt32 w)
{
    var t = x ^ (x << 11);

    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = w;

    return w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8);
}

void Main()
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        var x = rand.Next();
        var y = rand.Next();
        var z = rand.Next();
        var w = rand.Next();

        var u = XorShift128(x,y,z,w);
        var v = XorShift128((UInt32)x,(UInt32)y,(UInt32)z,(UInt32)w);

        if ((Int32)v != u) {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            Console.WriteLine(z);
            Console.WriteLine(w);
            Console.WriteLine(u);
            Console.WriteLine((Int32)v);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right-shifting a negative number does not shift the sign bit (`-2 >> 1 == -1`).

Comment: What's the point of the assignments in `XorShift128`? `x`, `y` and `z` are not used after the assignments.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, thank you! You've answered why my course work wasn't functioning right, it happened somewhere around 10 years ago ))) Now I know that for sure )))

Comment: @xxbbcc as for the point, you are right, there's no point in doing that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided in comments thanks to Phylogenesis:

```
-2 >> 1 == -1
```